# Redirecting the assert output from a dll, to a file

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke, assert, stderr

I have a C DLL called by a C# program.  The DLL is full of `assert()` statements, none of which are assertive enough to make it to my screen.  I understand this is because the assert output is written to STDERR (or maybe STDOUT).

Is there a way to somehow plug into the assert macro so that the output gets redirected to a file?

Comment: +1 Added C# and PInvoke instead of DLL so it get more .Net people to look at the question.

Comment: Are you sure that DLL is compiled for DEBUG (actually have asserts enabled)?

Comment: Yes, definitely enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the assertion reside in dll all passed?

I have following tested on Mono

```
#include <assert.h>
void foo()
{
    assert(1==2);
}

//~~~~~

[DllImport("mylib.so")]
extern static void foo();

public static void Main (string[] args)
{
  foo();
}
```

The program aborted immediately after the assertion failed.

If you just want to redirect stderr, `Console.SetError(new StreamWriter("err.log"));...;Console.Error.Close()` would suffice. But if the program aborted prematurely, `Console.Error` won't be properly closed, stream won't be flushed and nothing will be logged.

Comment: The problem is not that the program is not aborting.  It is that the reason for the abort is lost.  Not sure if your idea about using Console.SetError would work in a C++ DLL, but this is a C DLL